# jaspersoft studio 6.10.0 for java bean data source adapter no class def found error in

Tags: java, pdf, report, jaspersoft-studio

I created a jar with a data class and static generator function but when trying to create the adapter i was getting no class def found. even though i had added the jar to the project class path and had use the search feature to find the class and method.

Answer (score 0):

when i started work today the class just magically was working. only thing to happen in the mean time was a reboot. 
so i created a new data class. compiled to jar. and imported. same issue. restarted jaspersoft studio and boom test successful.

also i was able to get this working with kotlin based jar. need to add jars downloaded and restart JSS again. 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common